# does vld report false positives when checking memory leaks

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, mfc

when writing an mfc application and using vld to check for memory leaks are the results always correct.  it shows that cstring left, mid, right, and format are leaking memory.

is this a false positive or real?

Comment: Are using MFC 7.0 or 7.1? According to [Known Restrictions](https://vld.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Known%20Restrictions&referringTitle=Documentation) these versions aren't fully supported.

Comment: _mfc_ver is 0x0A00 which is 10 and the restrictions indicate that should work.

Comment: i've tried using the afx memory tools and even with DEBUG_NEW defined in stdafx and a rebuild, it won't provide module name and line number (this is debug mode so the definitions should be there to support this, especially since vld provides same)